# Parse a XML file in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

**I have a XML file where i need to read it and save each column to an excel file. Can someone pls help .

I have some lines after the declare statement , But I want to parse from the table1 till /table1
can someone help me ?

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Metadata" ?>
    <DECLARE  lmsid ="asdhgh"
     ...........
    </table1 name ="employee table" name ="E1 Enterprises" refid ="201"
     <data id = "ABC" emp = "dt">
     <country id ="m1" name =dt1">
     <rank text> "data"</rank text>
     <rank textd> "direction"</rank textd>
     <reference>
     <ref id ="9900m" id1="1000" ref="URL">
     </reference>
     </country>
    <data id = "xyz" emp = "dt1">
    <country id ="m2" name =dt2">
    <rank text> "data1"</rank text>
    <rank textd> "direction1"</rank textd>
    <reference>
    <ref id ="9900m" id1="2000" ref="URL">
    </reference>
    </country>
    </data id>
    ....
    </table1>
    </table1 name ="Manager table" name ="E1 Enterprises" refid ="202"
    <data id = "ARZ" emp = "dt">
    <country id ="m1" name =dt1">
     <rank text> "data"</rank text>
     <rank textd> "direction"</rank textd>
     <reference>
     <ref id ="9900m" id1="1000" ref="URL">
     </reference>
     </country>
     <data id = "QNC" emp = "dt1">
     <country id ="m2" name =dt2">
     <rank text> "data1"</rank text>
     <rank textd> "direction1"</rank textd>
     <reference>
     <ref id ="9900m" id1="2000" ref="URL">
     </reference>
     </country>
     </data id>
      ....
     </table1>
...
```

Thanks
Aarush 
**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

Comment: Please show that you did some research and made an earnest attempt. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried with Element tree, im able to get the values but im not sure how to save in excel also how to start the parsing from Table1.

Answer (score 0):

So I think you can just use BeautifulSoup to parse XML things. I found this snippet of code online

```
# Import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = []

# Read the XML file
with open("sample.xml", "r") as file:

    # Read each line in the file, readlines() returns a list of lines
    content = file.readlines()

    # Combine the lines in the list into a string
    content = "".join(content)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")

    #Do things
```

BS4 can find the xml tags pretty easy. Its docs are extensive, but something like `soup.find('data', id='xyz')` if you were looking for that info.
Then just export to csv with pandas or csv module.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by save each column. 
An XML has:
- tag name
- attributes
- text

You can use the xml.dom.minidom module

```
>>> s = '<t><a name="1"></a><a name="2"></a></t>'
>>> x = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(s)
>>> a = x.getElementsByTagName("a")
>>> for i in a:
...     print i.getAttribute("name")
...     
1
2
```

You can also parse a .xml file.
x = xml.dom.minidom.parse("c:\xmlFile.xml")

See more detail in the documentation:x = https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html

Once you have the value you want to save into your excel you can run a SQL statement with pyodbc and the microsoft odbc driver(Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)}):

```
import pyodbc

connection = pyodbc.connect("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)}; readonly=0; DBQ=C:\yourfileName.xlsx")

cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = "insert into [Sheet1$] (col1,col2) values (val1,val2)"
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: My output should look like in excel

table1                    name                   refid  data    emp  countryID  name ....
employee table     E1 Enterprises     201   ABC    dt      m1            dt1

each tag and its values to be populated to an excel sheet , Thats what i meant.

Comment: i've edit the above and added an example of how to insert data into excel via sql